# Is there any way to pass data to controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am using global exception class to handle all errors. In ExceptionHandling I use method

```
      private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
              //code ex.Message
             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Error");

        }
```

to return to the error action. I need to pass the exception that should viewed inside the error view. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom exception middleware like below.

```
using System.Net;

namespace MVCore6.Middleware
{
    public class ExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
                if(httpContext.Response.StatusCode== 404)
                {
                    await Handle404ExceptionAsync(httpContext,404);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //_logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {ex}");
                await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        ///  500 Error
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="exception"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?code=" + (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 404 Error for test
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="code"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Task Handle404ExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, int code)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?code="+code);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

And Register it in your Program.cs file.

```
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
        ...
```

**Home/Error Page**

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]

**Doc Link**

[You also can check the build-in middleware to check the exception.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0)